# Spring. How to keep beans.xml in the same folder as jar?

Tags: java, xml, spring

When I export my project to a `jar` file I want the `beans.xml` to be in the same folder as the `jar`

THe following works fine but `XmlBeanFactory` is deprecated

```
BeanFactory c = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("beans.xml"));
```

I tried this

```
ApplicationContext c= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

But this requires me to keep the `beans.xml`   in  resources subfolder

What is the correct code to replace the deprecated `XmlBeanFactory` and the `beans.xml` to be in the same folder as the `jar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext uses standard resource locations for XML bean definitions. Use GenericApplicationContext for more flexibility.

Example:

```
 GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
 xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource("beans.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're interested in an alternative to beans.xml, why don't you try the annotation route instead by using @Bean and @Configuration.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html